# Dynamics CRM 4 Async Service Jobs Waiting and HTTP Error 401.2

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

We're having an issue with Dynamics CRM 4.0.

Environment:

- Dynamics CRM Enterprise 4.0 Update Rollup 20
- Windows 2008 R2, SQL 2008 R2
- Platform and Database servers on separate virtual machines
- On-Premise deployment

We are using an imported organisation, the web site, outlook connectors and reports are all working without issue.

The issue we're having is that all workflows and system jobs are stuck in the Waiting status. Looking into the organisation database, we see a message like so:

```
Select Message from AsyncOperationBase where AsyncOperationId = 'SOMETHING';
```

We see a message that indicates the CrmService returned a 401 Unauthorized.

Using a browser, we can browse to:

```
http://crmserver/orgname/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx
```

and the service is correctly returned, however, when we browse to

```
http://crmserver/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx
```

we receive a 401.2 error.

Additionally, we can access the other services, such as the discovery service, via their normal path (without the org name). It's only the CrmService.asmx that displays the problem.

The CrmAsync and AppPool are all running under Network Service, and this issue is only affecting workflows.

We've tried Unpublishing/Republishing all workflows to no avail. We've run the IFD tool to ensure the server names are correctly set. We have uninstalled/re-installed.

Now we're stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was related to hosting WSUS on the same web application as the Dynamics CRM service.

Fixed the problem by reinstalling Dynamics CRM to its own web application.